# NodeJS child_process send input

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, io, child-process

I have a python script as follows :

```
print ("hello world ")
x = input("Enter a number: ")
print(x)
```

Now I want to programitically run the same using the below NodeJS code:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

child = spawn("python", ["./test.py"]);


child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`${data}`);
  child.stdin.write("7\n");
});
```

But the output isn't as expected and is like below:

```
hello world 
Enter a number: 
7
```

Is there any way I can send input to the node child process once the script awaiting for input?

Comment: It's not the problem, but you should declare that `child` variable. Right now, you're creating an implicit global.

Comment: That output looks right to me. Remember, you only see the `7` when you enter it because the console is echoing what you're providing as input, but nothing echoes what you're sending via `child.stdin.write` other than your final `print` call, whic is showing in the output you've provided.

Comment: Instead of `print(x)` if I do `print(x+5)` then I get nothing as output other than the initial print statement. So how can I pass an input to the python script and fetch the corresponding input in node?

Comment: If I make that change, I get `hello world` `Enter a number: ` `12` Sorry I can't be more help.